# Error renaming temporary file: Permission denied

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I have changed my HDD format from NTFS to ext4. I copied all the contents (~80 GB) to my external hard disk before formatting the partition. After the format I've copied all back to my internal HDD. Now when I open a pdf in Evince and trying to overwrite the file while saving; it gives this error (Error renaming temporary file: Permission denied). Before the format there wasn't such error.

My Ubuntu installation is in my other disk (SSD).

What may cause this problem?

Edit: I only have this problem with Evince Document Viewer. I've tried with Okular and did not have any problems. I also don't have any problems with other filetypes.

Regards,
Özgün

Comment: as a simple guess I would try to zap then reinstall using ... `sudo apt purge evince` and then
`sudo apt install evince`

Comment: Did it already; problem persists. Also I don't have any problems with documents stored in SSD for example. It causes this problem only on this specific HDD.

Comment: it might help you solve this by identifying location of the temp file ... wrap your launch of evince with strace which will show all files accessed ... `strace /usr/bin/evince /full/path/my/cool.pdf`  once you find temp file see if you can write to it directly